# is static variables cause memory leak in android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

is there is any chance of memory leak in static variable like in class

```
public class Date extends LinearLayout{

private static String VALUE="20";
    }
```

contexts , object references using static cause memory leak. But what about the constants variable declarations

Comment: it depends on what you store in the static variable

Comment: @Blackbelt if i store just a constant String ??like i mentioned in my question?

Comment: no, you are not leaking memory

Comment: only static contexts or views may cause memory leak? @Blackbelt

Comment: The answer Luba wrote is correct - you can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example will not cause a memory leak, but if you point to an activity or view context, it will.

So you can safely store any primitive static variable in your class.